# How to duplicate fields in custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types

Lately I've been using [Magic Fields](http://magicfields.org/) quite alot.
One of it's great advantages is the ability to duplicate a group - i.e. give the post/page author the ability do create multiple "meta-boxes" at will.

I would really like to switch to using wordpress native custom fields. Is there any way to achieve this "duplication" feature without the plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your looking for a simple way of creating/duplicating metaboxes and not duplicating the content added to those fields for a post. If I am correct in this assumption I have something absolutely fantastic to share with you... Its not a plugin but rather a class created by Dimas a true Wordpress Wizard. He has created a metabox class called "WPAlchemy_MetaBox" which essentially lets you do nearly anything you can think of without utilizing a plugin.

The downside is that if your coming from Magic Fields (which I am very familiar with) and you don't hack your own functions.php file then it will take a little while to get use to it. Once you get the hang of it though your going to be shocked at all the possibilities.

Below I are some of the core features/functions of the class. Recently he has been adding a bunch of excellent enhancements which I love and will soon have a screencast online.

The WPAlchemy_MetaBox PHP class can be used to create WordPress meta boxes quickly. It will give you the flexibility you need as a developer, allowing you to quickly build custom meta boxes for your themes and plugins.

Key Features and Benefits
Key Features and Benefits

- **Easy to learn and integrate:** good documentation and support is always important (I use the code myself and keep it up-to-date). Integration is a snap, as simple as including the class and using it.
- **Easy setup code:** some of the details involved in saving, retrieving and working with the meta data are abstracted to ease development.
- **Flexible usage:** the class acts as an aid for meta box development. By design you can use the class functions or your current development practices, which ever you feel most comfortable with for your development.
- **HTML and CSS separation:** the HTML and CSS for your meta boxes remain separate from the core code, you can design your meta boxes to your liking, providing you the greatest flexibility during development.

I HIGHLY recommend that everyone at least review this class and the features, your sure to love it.

- **Website:** http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/
- **GitHub Code:** http://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy